# Unattended upgrades stuck

Tags: linux, security, unattended-upgrades

I have a VM running `Ubuntu 20.04`.

I noticed that unattended upgrades were stuck due to the error:

```
Could not figure out development release: Distribution data outdated. Please check for an update for distro-info-data. See /usr/share/doc/distro-info-data/README.Debian for details.
```

The problem was solved by running

```
apt-get install --only-upgrade distro-info-data
```

The `/usr/share/doc/distro-info-data/README.Debian` reads:

```
Outdated Data Errors
====================

If you get an error that the package data is out of date, look for a newer
distro-info-data package in your distribution's updates.
```

So my question is what is the purpose of the `unattended-upgrades` package if these need to be manually over watched for such errors? (or am I missing something).

Does someone need to manually look after this package's state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of `unattended-upgrades` is to keep the system updated without user intervention (I imagine you know this, but your question asks that).

Presumably the configuration of `unattended-upgrades` on your system is such that `distro-info-data` upgrades are ignored. Given this, when `unattended-upgrades` needs updated distribution information (in all likelihood when a new release is made, although it’s not clear to me why an older release would need to know about this), it tells you about it.

Nothing needs to be done in `unattended-upgrades` itself. If you want to avoid this happening in the future, configure `unattended-upgrades` to apply `distro-info-data` updates. Technically the `unattended-upgrades` package could be updated to require a new enough `distro-info-data`, but that would only shift the problem to ensuring `unattended-upgrades` upgrades itself.

Comment: Τhanks for the elaborate answer; FWIW the `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades` file just has the default values so perhaps the "sane" defaults are not so sane to end up ignoring a package that prevents them from going on unattended..(question mark)

Comment: Yes, that’s possible; that’s why I was careful to avoid referring to “your configuration”, I thought it might just be the defaults and nothing to do with any changes you made (or didn’t).